# kernel module - netfilter hook on pre-routing, parallel or not?

Tags: parallel-processing, kernel, hook, netfilter

The question basically is : do netfilter hooks(kernel modules) run in parallel?

For example if i attach the hook on pre-routing and the hook is so complex that is busy processing the packet, when another packet arrives will there be another function started in parallel to process this packet?

The question is for single-core computers and multicore computers.

Comment: Same question. Sadly still no answer after over 3 years.